# How to compile /gazebo-8.0.0/examples/stand_alone/custom_main/custom_main.cc?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How to compile the /gazebo-8.0.0/examples/stand_alone/custom_main/custom_main.cc without install gazebo from source? Is there an example?  Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16828/how-to-compile-/gazebo-8.0.0/examples/stand_alone/custom_main/custom_main.cc?/) by [longwoo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3628/longwoo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It would be good for every example to have a README. These are the instructions:

```
# Build
cd <path to>/examples/stand_alone/custom_main
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
# Run
./custom_main
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longwoo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3628/longwoo/) on 2017-07-23**:
Thanks. it works.